# SSD M.2 cannot read after removing invalid GPT partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

My laptop has intel CORE i7 8th Gen processor.
I had Ubuntu Mate 22.04 on 256GB M.2 drive, and Windows 10 on another HDD drive.
I got a new 512GB NVMe and I wanted to clone my Ubuntu to it to use the bigger size.

When I used Clonezilla I got the following message:

`This disk contains mismatched GPT and MBR partitions`

I used the following command to remove GPT partition:

`sudo sgdisk -z /dev/sdc1`

But after I did that my 256GB M.2 cannot boot anymore and directs me to GRUB rescue.
I installed a fresh Ubuntu on the 512GB NVMe and connected the original 256GB M.2 using USB converter, but the 256GB is not readable anymore.

Now I need to repair the boot record of the 256GB drive, or at least get my files from it.